# How do I find company_id to use with Quip Admin API

Tags: quip, liveapps

I'm wanting to use the Quip Admin API endpoint documented here - https://quip.com/dev/admin/documentation#get-a-thread.

It requires a company_id supplied as a query parameter - where do I find the company id for my company?

Thanks,
Joel.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the company_id by going to admin console > Settings > site settings > and you will see company id under Site profile.